# Renaming file on server with python

Tags: python, file-upload

I have this code which allows uploading of files to a specific directory on my website, however, I want every file that is uploaded (which will only be a .txt file) to be renamed to "equations.txt" and then downloaded to my computer and then deleted from the server.

I need for example if someone uploads a file called "test.txt", it should upload it and then rename it to "equations.txt" on my server.

So far right now I got it to upload, but when I add the line:

> os.renames('/home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx.com/test/uploads/' + fn,
>   'equations.txt')

It actually deletes the `/uploads/` directory entirely instead of renaming the file in the directory to "equations.txt"...Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get filename here.
fileitem = form['filename']

# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:
   # strip leading path from file name to avoid 
   # directory traversal attacks
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   open('/home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx.com/test/uploads/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
   message = "The file " + fn + " was uploaded successfully"
   os.renames('/home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx.com/test/uploads/' + fn, 'equations.txt') ## Error line

else:
   message = "No file was uploaded"

print ("""\
Content-type: text/html\n\n
<html>
<body>
   <p>%s</p>
</body>
</html>
""") % (message)
```

Without the line added above the code works fine and uploads files to the `/uploads/` directory. So before I can move on to the next steps I need the renaming to work properly, thanks.

Comment: As an aside, with multiple users uploading simultaneously your design probably won't work the way you want.  Perhaps you already know this and the example in your Q is just simplified (in which case, thanks :) , so just FYI.

Comment: Right, it's not meant for the public, only a few people with private access will use it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `os.rename` instead of `os.renames`?

Also, try an absolute path for the dest.  So, this:

```
dest_dir = '/home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx.com/test/uploads/'
os.rename(dest_dir + fn, dest_dir + 'equations.txt')
```

instead of this:

```
os.renames('/home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx.com/test/uploads/' + fn, 'equations.txt')
```

Comment: Interesting, I did this and it seems to upload the file and rename it to "equations.txt" However, it uploads it to my cgi-bin directory?? I don't even mention the cgi-bin directory in the code...

Comment: Hmm, seems like a couple of separate things going on.  For the name change, I think os.rename is what you want.  As far as where the file lands, try using an absolute path for the dest.  I'll update my answer with an example.